# How to delete slave entity in entity framework poco in one line?

Tags: entity-framework, poco

The following code:

```
order.Orderlines.Remove(orderline)
```

Means not only to remove relationship between Order and Orderline but also to remove orderline from persistence permanently. Many slave entities have this situation.

As I know, in entity framework have to write extra code:

```
context.DeleteObject(orderline);
```

Or,

```
context.Orderlines.DeleteObject(orderline);
```

So, the remove rule can't be encapsulated entirely in order itself.

Any better choice for one line deletion in entity framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what you are asking, but here is [a very complete description of various scenarios for deleting related entities,](http://blogs.msdn.com/dsimmons/archive/2010/01/31/deleting-foreign-key-relationships-in-ef4.aspx) which will hopefully answer your question.